# Travelling from Narita airport to Sendai

Tags: japan, bookings, japan-rail, shinkansen

I arrive at Narita airport in early October at about 9am but need to get to Sendai. I thought of booking the Shinkansen from Tokyo (or Ueno?) for some suitable time (say, 11am), but I would like to know what would happen if my flight is delayed – is my ticket still valid and if so, how do I obtain a new seat reservation, since the JR East Hayabusa service apparently requires it?

I have read [this excellent question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66148/on-which-trains-in-japan-is-reservation-mandatory) but it doesn't seem to address my specific situation.

If I just turn up in Ueno to buy a ticket in the morning, are the prices significantly higher than buying e.g. a week in advance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: **Don't bother booking in advance, just show up and take an unreserved train.**

The fastest & easiest way from Narita to Sendai is to fly.  However, schedules have been cut due to COVID and ANA currently only flies 2x/week (!), which is unlikely to work for you.

Historically, no discounts were given for booking in advance on JR, the only thing this got you was a guaranteed seat.  However, outside peak periods like holidays, there are always unreserved seats available.  You *could* make a reservation and [change it for free](https://www.jreast.co.jp/multi/en/ticket/changes.html) if it looks like you're not going to make it, but this change has to be done in person at a station *and* before the original train departs, so you'd be out of luck if the flight is delayed.

These days, some discounted fares up to 30% are available, but the discounted fares typically have zero flexibility, so they are not a great fit for your situation.

So my recommendation is, just **show up at the station** and take the next unreserved train, they run every 20 minutes or so from Tokyo to Sendai.

Pro tip: instead of the obvious choice of JR Narita Express to Tokyo Station, take the Keisei Skyliner to Ueno and board the Shinkansen there.  This is cheaper, faster, and Ueno is a smaller and more navigable station too compared to the 3D labyrinth that is Tokyo Station.

Comment: Thank you – klar! That's what I'll do.

Comment: @user13190 Tell us how it went!

Comment: It went very well, thanks for asking: I did exactly as you suggested and the trains were frequent and not busy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you use to take the train:

- if you are using a regular ticket: according to the [rules](https://www.jr-odekake.net/railroad/ticket/guide/payback/change_miss_train.html), if you are late for a Hayabusa train, you will still be able to use any train on the same day, but technically you may not take a seat. In practice you may sit in any empty seat;
- if you are using a JR Pass or JR East Pass: of course, you just pretend you didn't reserve anything and just make a new reservation, which is for free anyways.

But a round trip between Tokyo Sendai + round trip Narita Express is already more expensive than a JR East Pass (Tohoku area), so I would suggest using the pass anyways.